javafx application won't launch and gives exception: NoSuchMethodError: notifyPreferencesChanged
I wrote an application using javafx and tested it on two computers and it worked fine. when I tried to launch the jar file of the app on my friend's computer for whom I wrote the program I got the following error
Exception in thread "JavaFX-Launcher" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: notifyPreferencesChanged
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.initIDs(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.<clinit>(WinApplication.java:111)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:39)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinPlatformFactory.createApplication(WinPlatformFactory.java:36)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:293)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:659)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:679)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff8f2b08082, pid=10752, tid=7420
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (21.0.2+13) (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0.2+13-LTS-58, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x448082]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\\hs_err_pid10752.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

we have the same operating system (windows 10 x64), the same JDK (21), and the same javafx (18).
note that before that I had trouble running javafx apps on my computer and and fixed it by copying the dll files from the 'lib' folder in javafx into the 'lib' folder in java and it worked fine. I also did the same thing on my friend's computer

Instructions on using JavaFX are at openjfx.io.  Follow them.  There is nothing in the instructions about "copying the dll files from the 'lib' folder in javafx into the 'lib' folder in java" - don't do that.  If you want a portable runtime, then follow the linked instructions about "Runtime images".

use the origin project code and compile on the deploy  environment. not only copy your dll or what else.

The initIDs method is a native method, so it appears some native code is trying to call a Java method named notifyPreferencesChanged. That method was added as part of the Platform Preferences API added in JavaFX 22. In short, it appears you have the native code for JavaFX 22 alongside JavaFX modules for JavaFX <= 21. The fix is to make sure you have the correct native code with your JavaFX application when deploying. A way to do this is to create a runtime image, as pointed out in jewelsea's comment.
